# I want to change carousel-item.active display property

Tags: slider, carousel

I want to change carousel-item.active display property block to flex.I change it in css but when I change slider it first gives display:block than make my cude run.display:flex,I want that bootstrap doesn't give  display:block than display:flex.Give only display:flex

Answer (score 0):

Set your CSS like this:

```
.carousel-item.active,
.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}
```

The `carousel-item-next` and `carousel-item-prev` classes are temporarily assigned to your slides during the transitions, so you have to make sure they have the same display property as the active slide.

If this isn't working, what version of Bootstrap are you using? I have tested it in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thedutchess/L5ou8jm6/).